# Return Asynchronous Data from Angular 2 Service

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, rxjs

I have a component in Angular 2 that calls a service and allows someone to login to Facebook. It works like this:

In my component I call my service with `this.facebook.login()`

And in my service, inside `login()`, I let someone login with `FB.login(res => { //do stuff with res });`

This pops up the Facebook auth window where you enter your username and password.

This is working great. After someone logs into their Facebook account, `res` has the data I need from Facebook. But what I really want to do is return the data back to my component so I can do stuff with it. How can I return this data after they have logged in with Facebook? I've tried with Observables, but I keep running into errors.

Comment: Could you show some code of what you've tried to get it to work?

Comment: I can't edit my question, but here's what I tried. In my component: `this.facebook.login().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });`. In my service:`return FB.login(res => { return res; });`. I think I'm treating something like an observable when it is not actually an observable, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code, I can't tell exactly, but you are on the right path. In your service, where you do the FB login, you need to make that return an observable so you can subscribe to.

```
public Login(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer: NextObserver<any>) => {
        // Do the FB login and wait for the data to come back
        FB.login(response => {
            // Return the data as an observable
            observer.next(<any>response);
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: cannot find name NextObserver. How to tackle this ?